# API resolved without sending a response for /api/users/create, this may result in stalled requests. NEXTJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, next.js, knex.js

I created an API endpoint to handle user account creation in my Next.js app, and I am using [knex.js](http://knexjs.org) to handle my queries, but I still get this error:

> ```
> API resolved without sending a response for /api/users/create, this may result in stalled requests.
> ```

My code in `/pages/api/users/create.js`:

```js
import { hash } from 'bcrypt';
import knex from '../../../knex';

export default async function regiterUser(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      hash(req.body.password, 10, async function (_, hash) {
        await knex('users').insert({
          name: req.body.name,
          email: req.body.email,
          role: 'user',
          allowed: true,
          password: hash,
        });
        res.end();
      });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(err).json({});
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can disable the warning (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012994/next-js-api-api-resolved-without-sending-a-response-for-api-employees-this-m/62016142#62016142)).

Comment: @NikolaiKiselev actually I have stalled request on my server, when the app keeps running for some time, I get an error that says : Too many clients. from the same endpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually the bcrypt *hash* function is an async function, it returns a promise to be either resolved with the encrypted data salt or rejected with an Error.

```
import knex from '../../../knex';

export default async function regiterUser(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const hashed = await hash(req.body.password, 10);
      await knex('users').insert({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        role: 'user',
        allowed: true,
        password: hashed,
      });
      res.status(200).end();
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(err).json({});
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405);
    res.end();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `else` block of `if` statement `res.end()` must be called.

```
} else {
  res.status(500)
  res.end()
}
```

To make API response clearer, consider using 405 status code instead of 500 in this case. 405 means method is not allowed (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)).

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure it is an async function and the add:

```
res.status(200) // for success
res.status(500) // enter code here`for failed
```