# any solution to API resolved without sending a response for /api/register, this may result in stalled requests.?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, next.js, bcrypt

I am doing a registration method in Next.js. I need to hash the password when I put it into the database so for that I use bcrypt. It seems working but if I call the registration API it outputs a warning which says:

> ```
> API resolved without sending a response for /api/register, this may result
> in stalled requests.
> ```

Here is my code:

```js
// imports and constants

export default async (req: any, res: any) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    //some variables and validation schema

    await db
      .collection(COLLECTION)
      .find({ email })
      .count()
      .then((result) => {
        if (result > 0) {
          return res.status(409).end();
        } else {
          bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then(function (hash) {
            // <----- THE PROBLEM IS HERE
            //password is the plainedPassword that I get from frontend
            user.password = hash;
            db.collection(COLLECTION).insertOne(user);
            return res.status(204).end();//<<--- the request doesn't end here but goes forward..
          });
        }
        // if I put another return.status(204).end(); here it works
      });
  } else {
    return res.status(405).end();
  }
};
```

It seems to be working, it stores the hash password into the DB, then I can make the login as well. However, I believe that warning could cause serious problems in the future.

I also logged a string before and after the `bcrypt` statement and I found out the problem is there.

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63339274/12860895) but it did not help me.

Comment: `db.collection(COLLECTION).insertOne(user)` operation returns promise use `await` or `.then()` to resolve then return `res`

Comment: can't use await there man! there is already at top level. the problem is bcrypt. idk what to do to solve it

Comment: Why can't you use await there man? top level await waits for find operation you need to resolve` insertOne` as well in order to know if the operation was success or not and also user is not defined in your snippet not sure if you are seeing any errors when trying to do user.password

Comment: man the real problem is that the flux doesn't stop at `return res.status(204).end()` but it goes forward. If I add another 'return statement' where I commented in the code above It works. Any suggestions to make it stop before?

Comment: have you tried resolving `db.collection(COLLECTION).insertOne(user);` using await or then to see if that helps. And also are you using mongoose or any mongoDB driver?

Comment: And also why are you using await and .then together?

Comment: It is hard to handle the find() output so I did it with then. However I think I will do it with findOne()

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was sending a POST request and expecting a response with a 200 that I wasn't receiving (with the same error that you have), so after that, my app couldn't continue with the normal workflow, the solution to that was sending a "dummy" response in json format, it could be something like:

```
return res.status(204).json({ message: "No content" });
```

It seems like nextjs always expect you to send some type of content.

Comment: Try calling `res.status(204).end();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning something from the `API` function, modify your code like this:

```js
return await db.collection()
```

Comment: doesn't change anything bro

Comment: hey bro I found where the problem is!! the problem is that  the request doesen't finish at:  `return res.status(204).end();` and it goes forward. i put another return after the brackets. But still.. how can I fix that? I just want it to finish where the return 204 statement is