# next.js Api route give me warning like / API resolved without sending a response for /api/*** this may result in stalled requests

Tags: axios, next.js

I'm using **next.js API Route with axios** and my api  gives me warning below

> API resolved without sending a response for /api/authentication/login,
> this may result in stalled requests.

I can't find what I'm doing wrong

```
import axios from 'axios'
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

const handler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): void => {
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers : { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
    url: `${process.env.WEB_API_URL}/authentication/login`,
    data: req.body,
  })
    .then((results) => {
      res.status(results.status).json(results.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(error.status).json(error.response.data)
    })
}

export default handler
```

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012994/next-js-api-api-resolved-without-sending-a-response-for-api-employees-this-m/62016142#62016142

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a promise there (your `axios` request) and you should return that. What's happening is that your api function is being called, a promise is kicked off, but the processing for your api call continues to the end (without waiting for the promise to resolve), and the api call ends with no response. You can solve this one of two ways - return the promise, or `await` the results of the `axios` call:

```js
// Option 1 - return the promise
import axios from 'axios'
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

const handler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
  return axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers : { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
    url: `${process.env.WEB_API_URL}/authentication/login`,
    data: req.body,
  })
    .then((results) => {
      res.status(results.status).json(results.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(error.status).json(error.response.data)
    })
}

export default handler
```

```js
// Option 2 - wait for the promise to resolve
import axios from 'axios'
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const results = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      headers : { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
      url: `${process.env.WEB_API_URL}/authentication/login`,
      data: req.body,
    })
    res.status(results.status).json(results.data)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(error.status).json(error.response.data)
  }
}

export default handler
```

Note that I added `Promise` to your function return signature, but `Promise<void>` is not right. I don't know anything about your data structure, so you'd want to change `void` to whatever that actually looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I add up the answer from GitHub

It is probably because cors middleware isn't awaiting next().

```
// BAD: This will lead to UnhandledPromiseRejection
router
  .use(async (req, res, next) => {
    next();
  })
  .use(async (req, res, next) => {
    next();
  })
  .use(async () => {
    throw new Error("");
   });

// GOOD
router
  .use(async (req, res, next) => {
    await next(); // next() is awaited, so errors are caught properly
  })
  .use((req, res, next) => {
    return next(); // this works as well since we forward the rejected promise
  })
  .use(async () => {
    throw new Error("");
   // return new Promise.reject("");
  });
```